# Is it possible to include ALL fields from joined table EXCEPT joined one?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Very often join fields have the same name in joined tables. If just join

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
```

it will produce `id` field twice.

Is it possible to include ALL fields from joined table EXCEPT joined one?

**UPDATE**

I am using MySQL but standard way is also interesting to me!

**UPDATE 2**

Regarding `USING` syntax, how to use it with multiple joins?

```
SELECT * FROM 
   a INNER JOIN b USING (b_id)
     INNER JOIN c USING (c_id)
```

swears table `b` doesn't contain `c_id` field, which is true, since it is inside `a`.

Normally I would write

```
SELECT * FROM 
   a INNER JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.b_id
     INNER JOIN c ON a.c_id = c.c_id
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using, as I suspect the answer may depend on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard SQL this is achieved through `USING`

```
select *
from a 
  join b using (id);
```

This will return the `id` column only once.

Comment: Thanks. But what if multiple joins? See my update please.